# Data not syncing from component.ts to template

Tags: angular, routes, angular9

I have a navigation bar in the `app.component.html` which is need to show in every page. I need to **show this navigation bar to the logged in users only**. In `app.component.ts` I am checking whether the user is logged in or not by calling the **`authService`** from ngOnInit() lifecycle method. But after geting the **`isLoggedIn`** data its not refelecting in the `app.component.html`. I am navigating to the root component from login component after a successfull login , then its not showing the navigations OR the **`isAuthenticated`** variable is not taking in to effect when the navigation is done. **`But After a reload it shows the navigation`**. How to resolve this issue? Thanks.

## app.component.html

```
 <ul *ngIf="isAuthenticated">
    <li><a class="active" href="/home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/addContact">Add User</a></li>
    <li><a href="/listContact">List Users</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown right">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">{{userDetails.userName}}</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Profile</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Reset Password</a>
        <a href="#" (click)="logout($event)">Logout</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

## app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './_services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  userDetails = {
    userName: '',
    userToken: ''
  }
  isAuthenticated = false;
  constructor(public authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUserDetails()
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {

  }

  getUserDetails() {
    this.userDetails.userName = this.authService.getUserName()
    this.userDetails.userToken = this.authService.getToken()
    if (this.userDetails.userToken && this.userDetails.userName) {
      this.isAuthenticated = true;
    }
  }
  logout(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (this.authService.signOut()) {
      this.isAuthenticated = false;
      this.router.navigate(['/login'])
    }
  }
}
```

## login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from "../../_services/auth.service";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  login = {
    username: '',
    password: ''
  }

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  loginContact() {

    const data = {
      username: this.login.username,
      password: this.login.password
    }
    if (data) {
      this.authService.signIn(data).subscribe(
        res => {
          var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
          if (result) {
            localStorage.setItem("token", result.accessToken);
            localStorage.setItem("userName", result.username);
            console.log("logged in successfully")
            this.router.navigate(['/home']);
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
          }

        },
        error => {
          console.log(error)
          alert("Signin failed " + JSON.stringify(error))
        }
      )
    }
  }
}
```

## login.component.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Login Form</h2>

<form class="login_form" name="login_form" (ngSubmit)="loginContact()" method="post">
  <div class="imgcontainer">
    <img src="assets/img/img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required [(ngModel)]="login.username">

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required [(ngModel)]="login.password"> 

    <button type="submit">Login</button>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
    <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
    <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
  </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with `BehaviorSubject`

first declare `public isAuthenticated$: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;`

then on `ngOnInit()` set its default state `this.isAuthenticated$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);`

change inside function `getUserDetails()` to `this.isAuthenticated$.next(true);`

lastly in your template `*ngIf="isAuthenticated$ | async"`.

Comment: Okay, let me check

Comment: When i printed isAuthenticated$ in the template it shows Object Object instead of true or false

Comment: you should add json pipe {{ isAuthenticated$ | async | json}}

Comment: Your solution didn't worked actually!, first i thought it worked. As @Anil Kumar pointed out the app component is already initialized and **even if isAuthenticated$ is true**, it only reflecting after re rendering the app component. I initialized the `this.isAuthenticated$ = new BehaviorSubject(false)` in ngOnInit() and in getUserDetails after successfull login i given `this.isAuthenticated$.next(true);` which in turn makes isAuthenticated to true. But it still print `false` in template

Answer (score 1):

When you are in login route app.component is already initialized so when you successfully logged in and you are redirecting to home and as I said app.component was already initialized so it will not run ngOnIt again. So for this problem, you should use `rxjs Subjects`

or you can simple use different container components, for example: one auth container component and another one for all your routes layout container component. this pattern will structure your app and also easy to maintain.

@Crazyrubixfan Here is example of better app structure: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scfdfb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodules%2Fcore-layout%2Fcore-layout.component.html

Comment: How to structure in that way you mentioned? I created a navbar component and moved the navbar show and hide logic to there and included the selector in app component. And used `rxjs Subjects` to asynchronously get isAuthenicated details from a Auth service. It didn't work either as `navbar` component was already initialized

Comment: [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scfdfb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodules%2Fcore-layout%2Fcore-layout.component.html)

Comment: Thanks @Anil Kumar, Will give it a try

Comment: Yeah, now i understood the `auth layout`  works only for `auth routes` and is independent of `core layout` right? `navbar` comes under `core layout` and it wont show in `auth routes` and will show in all `core routes` right? This is my understanding

Comment: Yes absolutely right and this way you don't have to use unnecessary rxjs subjects and observables

Answer (score 0):

I added an `Observer` with `SetInterval` function that check authenticated or not in a time interval in app.component.ts and used that variable in template.

I don't know if this method is correct or not(probably wrong)

## app.component.ts

```
isAuthenticatedObs = new Observable<boolean>((observer: Observer<boolean>) => {
    setInterval(() => observer.next(this.authService.isAuthenticated())
      , 1000);
  });
```

## app.component.html

```
<ul *ngIf="isAuthenticatedObs | async">
    <li><a class="active" href="/home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/addContact">Add User</a></li>
    <li><a href="/listContact">List Users</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown right">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">{{userDetails.userName}}</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Profile</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Reset Password</a>
        <a href="#" (click)="logout($event)">Logout</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Please suggest me a better method if you have. Thanks.